# How to get Google Advertisement ID in Ionic3?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, google-advertising-id

Hi we tried to get Advertisement ID using ionic3 application.We added plugin

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-idfa --save**

We tried like this

ONE:

```
cordova.plugins.idfa.getInfo().then(function(info) {
      if (!info.limitAdTracking) {
          console.log('OK getting ID**********'+info.idfa || info.aaid);
      }
      });
```

we are getting get  **Cannot read property 'getInfo' of undefined**

TWO:

```
    declare var androidIDFA;

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html',
    })
    export class MyApp {
    googleAddId:any;

if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    androidIDFA. getAdId(
      (addId) => {
        console.log(addId);
        this.googleAddId=addId.adId;
      },
      (e) => {
        console.log(e);
       //This error message not works on Desktops
      }
    );
  }
```

We are getting **androidIDFA is not defined**.Let me know what we missed here.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-idfa) the plugin you are using?

Comment: @SurajRao thanks for reply .Yes am using same plugin

Comment: Hmm.. your first one seems to be as per the documentation.. You might want to raise an issue in github.